# Batch use string variable in parameter

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have been experimenting with batch (64bit) and I need to know how to use a variable as a parameter.
For example, if I have

```
set /p prog=Your favorite program is:
call prog
```

That originally looked fine to me, but if I entered (echo is on)

```
I:\TEST>set /p prog=Your favorite program is:
Your favorite program is:notepad.exe
```

It returns (echo is still on)

```
I:\TEST>call prog
'prog' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Anyone know how to make it so the file runs `call notepad.exe` when I enter `notepad.exe`, and not `call prog`?

Comment: I understand that recommending to read manual is not acceptable, but please consider it as an option - `set /?` and `call /?`...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I tried that and I couldn't find anything meaningful or I'm just too tired...

Comment: Not even single sample of using variables??? `set VAR=before
 if "%VAR%" == "before" (...` - notice `%VAR%`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ...yup, I'm an idiot...and I should probably get some sleep... PS: I though I tried that but apparently I didn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling variables is used by percent signs (%).

```
call %prog%
```

This grabs the whole var. If you have more that one word in the program name, do

```
call "%prog%"
```

instead.